# How to iterate through data table to check element text matches within data table

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a question in regards to dataTable in cucumber. If I have the following dataTable:

```
Then the following options are displayed
  | A          |
  | B          |
  | C          |
```

I want to perform an assertion to iterate through each element and check that its text matches with any of the options from the dataTable. How is this done?

Below is what I have so far:

```
    @Then("^the following options are displayed$")
    public void  the_following_options_are_displayed(DataTable options) throws Throwable {
        List<List<String>> data = options.raw();
        List<WebElement> optionsIcons = driver.findElements(By.className("options-icons"));

        for (WebElement optionsIcons : optionsIcon) {

            //Here is where I am stuck

            }
```

I am struggling to implement the example question given as this relates to a class so just need a little guidance with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Iterate Datatable with type List<Class> in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117502/how-to-iterate-datatable-with-type-listclass-in-cucumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code checks for all elements that contains at least one of those options. If an element does not contains any of these options, it will give an assertion message.

**Cucumber Feature**

```
Then the following options are displayed 
        | option1 | optionText | 
        | option2 | optionText2 |
        | option3 |  optionText3|
```

**Java Class**

```
@And("^the following options are displayed$")
public void the_following_options_are_displayed(DataTable options) {
List<List<String>> data = options.raw();
List<WebElement> optionsIcons = driver.findElements(By.className("options-icons"));
int count = 0;
for (WebElement optionsIcon : optionsIcons) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

        if(optionsIcon.getText().contains(data.get(i).get(1))==true){
            count ++;

        }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue("There is no match found with these options", count!=0);

    }
}
```